# Monodevelop exception at startup: TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I recently updated mono to the latest version 4.0.2 and ever since, Monodevelop won't start.

I tried to purge all packages associated with mono and monodevelop

- mono-complete
- mono-runtime
- monodevelop

I remembered, that I had tried to compile mono from source, quite some time ago. Therefore I manually removed all folders named mono from

- usr/bin
- usr/local/bin
- usr/lib
- usr/local/lib
- usr/etc
- usr/local/lib

After that, I was rather sure that mono was removed completely. I tried to find remains with mlocate and whereis but the system seemed clean.
Then I installed
 - mono-complete
 - monodevelop

Monodevelop still crashes.

This is the output of monodevelop:
http://pastebin.com/AmGsXB4M

Here is a more detailed version:
http://pastebin.com/YB0rkBgV

Mono is the latest version:

```
mono --version

Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 10:04:37 UTC 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

The monodevelop version should be the latest, too. But I can't check since

```
monodevelop --version
```

provokes the same crash.

My os is ubuntu 15.04 64-bit.

**UPDATE:**

The monodevelop version is 5.9.4
http://pastebin.com/EkL1wnH7

Comment: Trying running "monodevelop --help" to get the version as "monodevelop --version" starts the GUI since --version is not a cmd line option. This will let you see if the crash is related to the GUI or not.

Comment: Ok, that works. The version is 5.9.4

Comment: please paste the full exception! just saying `TypeInitializationException` is not enough information

Comment: The full exception is on pastebin, just follow the links

Answer (score 0):

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MonoDevelop.Core.LoggingService ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section <runtime> (/usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe.config line 3)
```

It appears there is a mismatch in your install. If you look at the debug output in provided, you loading assemblies from /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib.

I would look at the mono configs that it is picking up and might sure that it not finding an old 3.x dll map file:

```
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/lars/.mono/config'.
```

A 'clean' monodevelop 5.9.x startup on Ubuntu 15.04 : [gist](https://gist.github.com/sushihangover/9d53246d046d2a8b2831)

A monodevelop.exe.config 5.9.x file : [gist](https://gist.github.com/sushihangover/4918e7381d85618fff05)

Comment: Those two config files don't exist.